# Variable not in scope in Haskell. What does this mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter =  (\x -> x % 2 == 0) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

using the code below in Haskell when run I get an error :
'Variable not in scope:
(%) :: [Integer] -> Bool -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]'

What does this mean ?

Im trying to create a function that takes list and returns the even numbers. Being so new to haskell this is all I've managed but I still get an error. I have googled butI cannot find a solution

Comment: Your first line is the proper type signature of the `filter` library function. Your second line is a redefinition of `filter`, which hides the definition from the library. The compiler is trying to *unify* your definition of filter with its correct type from the library.

Answer (score 4):

It simply means that `%` is not defined.

When I open the ghci shell and ask for the type of the `+` and `%` operators, I see that `+` is defined, but for `%` I get the same error:

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t (%)

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: %
```

Modulus is available as the `mod` function.

There are a few other problems in your example though:

- there already is a function named `filter` in prelude
- you are passing argument (a list of ints) in the function definition
- you are passing a list of ints to a lambda function which accepts a single int